# OptionMenu in tkinter keeps crashing when placed in a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place an OptionMenu widget inside of a frame, which itself is inside of a notebook. From what I've found online, the code for doing this is roughly:

```
    # add a drop down menu
    hops = range(0,6)
    self.selectedHop = StringVar(frame2)
    self.selectedHop.set(hops[0])
    self.hopOptions = OptionMenu(frame2, self.selectedHop, *hops)
    self.hopOptions.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=EW)
```

However, when I place this in my code in the code below (the chunk above is placed towards the bottom of it, and is labeled "PROBLEMATIC CODE..."), my app just freezes and I have to force quit it, and I have no error message to debug with. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import subprocess
import sys

class ReportGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master

        master.title('Reporting')
        master.resizable(True, True)
        master.configure(background = '#b3e6cc')
        master.minsize(width=800,height=700)

        textcolor = "#003399"

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('TFrame', background = '#e1d8b9')
        self.style.configure('TButton', background = '#e1d8b9')
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background = '#e1d8b9', font = ('Arial', 40))
        self.style.configure('Header.TLabel', font = ('Arial', 30, 'bold'))      

        # step 1 - create notebook
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)
        self.notebook.pack()

        # step 2 - create first frame to add to notebook
        self.frame_logon = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        # step 3 - add first frame to notebook and style it
        self.notebook.add(self.frame_logon, text = 'Login')                
        self.frame_logon.config(padding = (20, 20, 20))
        self.frame_logon.config(relief = RIDGE)

        ######### --- (1) LOGIN TAB ----  #########
        label = ttk.Label(self.frame_logon, text = 'Administrative Reporting', 
            foreground=textcolor, style = 'Header.TLabel')
        label.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2)

        # widget: username and password Label()
        label2 = ttk.Label(self.frame_logon, text = 'Username:',
            font = ('Arial', 17),foreground=textcolor)
        label2.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')

        label3 = ttk.Label(self.frame_logon, text = 'Password:',
            font = ('Arial', 17),foreground=textcolor)
        label3.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')

        # widget: entry boxes Entry()
        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self.frame_logon, width = 20, font = ('Arial', 15))
        self.entry_pw = ttk.Entry(self.frame_logon, width = 20, font = ('Arial', 15))

        # place the widgets
        self.entry_name.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5)
        self.entry_pw.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_pw.config(show = '*') # make password not show

        # widget: connect button Button()
        self.loginButton = ttk.Button(self.frame_logon, text = 'Connect',
                   command = self.login)
        self.loginButton.grid(row = 5, column = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = 'e')

    ### COMMAND FUNCTIONS
    def login(self):
        # Make connections (TBA)
        # 1) log into app
        # 2) ssh into server port
        # 3) connect to database

        # if successful login and connection, launch reports tab

        self.reportTab()
        self.notebook.select(1) # switch tabs to reports tab
        self.loginButton.state(['disabled']) # disable login button

    # TAB 2: reporting tab
    def reportTab(self):

        # create report frame and add to notebook
        self.frame_report = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.frame_report, text = 'Report Options')

        ######### --- REPORT TAB ----  #########

        #--------- FILTER 1: -----------
        frame = ttk.Frame(self.frame_report)
        frame.grid(row=1,column=0)
        frame.config(height = 100, width = 200)
        frame.config(relief = RIDGE)
        ttk.LabelFrame(frame, height=100,width = 200,text = 'FILTER 1').pack()  

        #--------- FILTER 2: -----------
        frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_report)
        frame2.grid(row=1,column=1)
        frame2.config(height = 100, width = 200)
        frame2.config(relief = RIDGE)
        ttk.LabelFrame(frame2, height=100,width = 200,text = 'FILTER 2').pack()

        #---------- PROBLEMATIC CODE: trying to add a drop down menu ----
        hops = range(0,6)
        self.selectedHop = StringVar(frame2)
        self.selectedHop.set(hops[0])
        self.hopOptions = OptionMenu(frame2, self.selectedHop, *hops)
        self.hopOptions.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=EW)
        #----------------------------------------------------------------

        #--------- FILTER 3:  -----------
        frame3 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_report)
        frame3.grid(row=2,column=0)
        frame3.config(height = 100, width = 200)
        frame3.config(relief = RIDGE)
        lbf3 = ttk.LabelFrame(frame3, height=100,width = 200,text = 'FILTER 3')
        lbf3.pack()

        #--------- FILTER 4:  -----------
        frame4 = ttk.Frame(self.frame_report)
        frame4.grid(row=2,column=1)
        frame4.config(height = 100, width = 200)
        frame4.config(relief = RIDGE)
        ttk.LabelFrame(frame4, height=100,width = 200,text = 'FILTER 4').pack()

        # code for calling queries TBA

        # launch results tab if queries successful

        # self.resultsTab()

    def func(self,value):
        print(value)

    # TAB 3: results tab
    def resultsTab(self):

        # create results frame and add to notebook 
        self.frame_results = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.frame_results, text = 'Results')

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry_pw.delete(0, 'end')
        self.text_comments.delete(1.0, 'end')

def main():            

    root = Tk()
    hccwgui = ReportGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the error message, and please don't link to code on another site. You might want to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: we are too lazy to download file from other server, and run it to see error message. Put in question code (or part of code which was mentioned in error message) and full error message.

Comment: Sorry there is no error message because the app just freezes and I have to Force Quit it. I've pasted my code above instead of linking it. Is there anything else I can do to help you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# ...
ttk.LabelFrame(frame2, height=100,width = 200,text = 'FILTER 2').pack()
# ...
self.hopOptions = OptionMenu(frame2, self.selectedHop, *hops)
self.hopOptions.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=EW)
```

This is your problem. You're packing a LabelFrame in frame2, and then trying to grid something in frame2. A given container can only use one of `grid()` or `pack()`- using both won't cause an error, but the two managers will negotiate on how to place things for the rest of your lifetime.

The solution is to make sure that a given container's children are either packed or gridded, but never both in the same container (though you could have a structure `parent->child->grandchild`, where child is packed in parent and grandchild is gridded in child).

Comment: Thank you so much! All set now.